# Should I learn ASP.NET AJAX, jQuery or both?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm .NET developer. Most of my career I worked on web based intranet applications (ASP.NET WebForms) but always as a server side developer. Client side development was done by my colleagues more skilled in JavaScript and different JS frameworks. At the moment I have some JavaScript skills and very elementary understanding of both ASP.NET AJAX (I mean client side library) and jQuery. It mostly means that I can read JS code and I can write very simple functions. I would like to be better in this area and I'm planning to learn some of these technologies. Should I learn both ASP.NET AJAX and jQuery or skip ASP.NET AJAX and go directly to jQuery? By learning I mean really deep understanding of concepts and whole framework.

At the moment I'm reading [Introducing Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624135) but I'm not very happy with it. It doesn't have coverage I would expect. I have already bought [ASP.NET AJAX in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988142) and [jQuery in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182323). Do you recommend me any other sources?

**Edit:** So nobody defends ASP.NET AJAX? It looks like this API exists only to fill some MS certification exams.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery is more than enough. Couple this with [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and you will never ever need to  look at Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX (or whatever its name is currently). Even if you work with standard ASP.NET WebForms, jQuery will be sufficient.

Also note that [Microsoft have fully embraced jQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx) (it is included with ASP.NET MVC) and they are actively supporting its development. I won't be surprised if MS AJAX becomes obsolete soon (for me personally it's been deprecated for years :-)).

So I would recommend you use the time you would have wasted in learning MS AJAX in improving your jQuery skills.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is other topic. I like it and I want to use it in our projects but company policy doesn't allow it at the moment. I didn't mentioned ASP.NET MVC because than, jQuery would be easy choice.

Comment: MS AJAX becomes obsolete side by side ASP.NET Web Forms becomes obsolete. However don’t forget that the MS AJAX is used for creating JavaScript proxies for script Web Services and script WCF Services.

Comment: @Petr Pechovic:I do not think ASP.NET Wb Forms will become obsolete; even after the 10-year-support promise Microsoft has it is over. WebForms is way better for quick-and-dirty apps than MVC (which some businesses need). Plus, there are some developers who LOVE the evil WebForms lets you do easily (mix business and data logic with UI, mix UI content with UI management etc.) I expect WebForm to linger on for quite a while. However, personally, I shy away from it because I hate it's associated gunk/abstractions.

Answer (score 2):

Try to learn ajax from scratch, with plain javascript, it helps you understand how it works. Then go to jQuery.

Comment: I already did it. I played with XmlHttpRequest directly. But this question is not only about AJAX but about whole frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Though the server side part of ASP.NET Ajax, the updatepanel for example, are still quite popular for server side developers to add that little bit of ajax like behavior in their pages I strongly suggest you learn jQuery. Microsoft also decided to put effort into jQuery and favor that as their primary suite: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/16/microsoft-jquery-and-templating.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answers above. ASP.NET AJAX isn't real ajax, because you are effectively sending the entire page back to the server as ViewState, going through the entire page-load cycle, and then returning a bunch of stuff back to the client. It's all really just an illusion, which will leave you disappointed, especially in terms of capabilities and performance. jQuery isn't very difficult to get your head around, and you'll be amazed at what you can accomplish with relatively minimal effort.

Comment: I disagree. As I understand it, this happens only if you use UpdatePanel. But pure AJAX calls to services don't send ViewState and other stuff. But again this question is not only about AJAX but about client side programming.